# Wrong Language of GTK applications in Kubuntu

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, kde, gtk, language-support

I have Kubuntu 14.04, and am running some GTK applications, for example Shotwell.

The "Preferred Languages" in the locale settings are set to:

1. English
2. German
3. French

All the application interfaces should be in English but I added German and French to have spell checking available.

For some reason, the interface language for GTK applications is now German, but only when I launch them from the KDE main menu. When I launch from the Konsole they are in English.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I have a similar issue, on KXStudio 14.04 with KDE 4.13.3. Most of my GUIs are in English, but Evolution and some terminal output are in French. However, starting Evolution from the terminal does not change the language to English. Will post here if I find anything.

Comment: This fixed my problem with Evolution: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=152641 (See the last post, which summarises it all.)
It could be that the language packs you have in `/usr/share/locale-langpack/en/LC_MESSAGES/` are outdated if you have more recent app versions.

Comment: Did you find a suitable system wide solution?